# How to prove that a non-euclidean shape is infinite or finite?

Tags: calculus, geometry, infinity, noneuclidean-geometry

There are mainly three theories about the shape of the universe: it can have a shape with zero curvature (flat), positive curvature (spherical) or negative curvature (hyperbolic). My question is "How can we prove that a non-euclidean shape is infinite or finite?" Mathematically, is there any way to prove that a hyperbolic shape is infinite ? Should I use limits or something else?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! A few potential ambiguities make this difficult to address at face value: 1. The cosmology literature often mistakenly presumes that a manifold of negative curvature has infinite volume. 2. A hyperbolic manifold can have infinite length and finite volume; what exactly does "infinite" mean to you? 3. If you're asking about empirical cosmology, there's the additional constraint that information propagates at the speed of light, so we _cannot_ observationally prove the universe has infinite length, only fail to prove it has finite volume. Could you please clarify? Thank you.

Comment: I am writing a mathematical essay so it is totally fine,even better,to analyse a misconception.In this essay, my aim is to prove a real life stiuation mathematically.So my real life situation is the shape of the universe.Scientist stated these three main shapes, right?But how did they reach to these conclusions?Maybe they made these claims because according to the hyperbolic shape theory,the universe is expanding.So how did mathematicians prove that any of these three shapes have a finite/infinite length or volume?(Please correct me if I made any mistake in terms of knowledge, thank so much!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematically one usually studies *manifolds* of *constant* curvature. These properties pretty much define the manifold, so everything else can be concluded from that. But the real universe definitely doesn't have constant curvature, as masses cause additional spacetime curvature. And while the concept of manifold entails that you'll never “hit a wall”, there is nothing to say that this holds for the real universe.

By analogy, you can't distinguish a sphere from a hemisphere until you see the boundary, or have explored half the sphere without finding one.